# Monkey-patching jest object for all test files

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, monkeypatching

How can I monkey-patch some methods in the global `jest` object for all test files at once? I don't want to add any extra code to my test files, it has to be done somewhere in setup and it can be an ugly hack.

I tried doing that from a custom environment, `setupFiles` and `setupFilesAfterEnv`, but it looks like they all get a different instance of `jest` object and my changes aren't visible in test files.

Disclaimer: I know that it's a bad thing to do but I need it for some one-time benchmarking only and it's the easiest solution that gets the job done.

Comment: I haven't gotten this working yet, but I found an article that describes something similar. It says to monkey patch the `jest-runtime` module. http://www.petecorey.com/blog/2019/03/25/bending-jest-to-our-will-restoring-nodes-require-behavior/

Answer (score 1):

I got this working! You're right, Jest does re-construct the global `jest` object for every test case, but you can override the function it uses to do that. In `jest.config.js`, set `globalSetup` to something like `<rootDir>/jest-global-setup.js`. Then, in `jest-global-setup.js`, add this:

```js
const jestRuntime = require('jest-runtime');

const { _createJestObjectFor } = jestRuntime.prototype;

jestRuntime.prototype._createJestObjectFor = function(...args) {
    // Call the original function to create a normal jest object.
    const jestObject = _createJestObjectFor.apply(this, args);

    // Apply your changes.
    jestObject.isMonkeyPatched = true;
    
    // Return the patched object.
    return jestObject;
}

// Jest expects to find a function of some sort as well, 
// but we don't need it for this example.
module.exports = function() { /* do nothing */ }
```